# Selenium returns img src as base64

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to download photos from page using Selenium in Python that way:

```
  options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  driver.get(url)
  time.sleep(10)
  name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2[class="uitk-toolbar-title-content"]').text
  images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
  driver.quit()
  return [
      image.get_attribute('src') for image in images
      if image.get_attribute('src').startswith('https://images')
  ], name
```

On page there is i.e. 70 photos and I download only 5.
When I look in source HTML code on page in browser there is img tag:

```
<img alt="Minibar, desk, free cribs/infant beds, WiFi" class="uitk-image-media" src="https://images.trvl-media.com/lodging/2000000/1160000/1157300/1157224/72931ae3.jpg?impolicy=resizecrop&amp;rw=1200&amp;ra=fit">
```

But when I save to file source code I get by `driver.get(url)` I have:

```
<img alt="Minibar, desk, free cribs/infant beds, WiFi" class="uitk-image-media" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
```

Why images src has same `base64` url and not standard url? Only few images have normal url. How to change it?
I tried using `WebDriverWait` or BeautifulSoup, but effect is the same.

Comment: Hard to know without looking at the website directly. If you open the page with `view-source:` before the url what is the src?

Comment: https://www.hoteles.com/en/ho572087/bahia-calma-beach-pajara-spain/?chkin=2023-09-15&chkout=2023-09-19&destType=MARKET&destination=Pajara%2C%20Canary%20Islands%2C%20Spain&expediaPropertyId=13461879&latLong=28.350619%2C-14.108076&neighborhoodId=6049907&pwaThumbnailDialog=thumbnail-gallery&pwa_ts=1694779934296&referrerUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaG90ZWxlcy5jb20vSG90ZWwtU2VhcmNo&regionId=182358&rfrr=HSR&rm1=a2&searchId=ea11e221-09ee-419a-ac65-9331937627c8&selected=1157224&selectedRatePlan=286251325&selectedRoomType=219960804&sort=RECOMMENDED&top_cur=USD&top_dp=105&useRewards=false&userIntent=&x_pwa=1

Comment: @Daviid this the example page, I want to download all photos

Comment: Selenium's get page source method will return the current DOM at the time it is called... (similar to right-clicking on the browser and choosing "inspect").  View Page Source returns the page before DOM is modified by JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wait for site to be fully rendered, so you don't get correct amount of images.

Images in gif format that you got are not needed, as far as they have resolution 1x1 and are minor elements of design (tooltip components, etc.)
For sure, you can decode them to the image, using, for example, `PIL`, but what is the purpose?

Instead of it, you can filter images by containing 'https' in their src and wait for array values to stop changing (as an example how you can wait for render). Or if you know proper condition, when the site is fully rendered - you can use it instead of my function.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(value_func, timeout=10, interval=2):
    start_time = time.time()
    value = None
    while value_func() != value:
        value = value_func()
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not stop changing within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)
    return value

def get_images():
    return driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[src*=https]')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.hoteles.com/en/ho572087/bahia-calma-beach-pajara-spain/?chkin=2023-09-15&chkout=2023-09-19&destType=MARKET&destination=Pajara%2C%20Canary%20Islands%2C%20Spain&expediaPropertyId=13461879&latLong=28.350619%2C-14.108076&neighborhoodId=6049907&pwaThumbnailDialog=thumbnail-gallery&pwa_ts=1694779934296&referrerUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaG90ZWxlcy5jb20vSG90ZWwtU2VhcmNo&regionId=182358&rfrr=HSR&rm1=a2&searchId=ea11e221-09ee-419a-ac65-9331937627c8&selected=1157224&selectedRatePlan=286251325&selectedRoomType=219960804&sort=RECOMMENDED&top_cur=USD&top_dp=105&useRewards=false&userIntent=&x_pwa=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[src*=https]')))
images = wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(get_images)
for img in images:
    data = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(data)

print(len(images))
```

if you still want to get from `base64` string, you can proceed with smth like this

```py
import base64
import io
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
images = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img')

for i in range(len(images)):
    src = images[i].get_attribute('src')
    if ('data:' in src):
        data = src.split(',')[1]
        decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(data)
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded_bytes))
        image.save(f'decoded_image_{i}.gif')
    else:
        # proceed with link
```

But, as I mentioned above, this doesn't make any sense.

**UPD**:

After getting all info from you, I can assume that your case is tricky.

1. After page load you have redirect to tab with grid.
2. Tab itself is not focused and doesn't contain all images - they are rendered on scroll async.
3. Native JS scroll or scrolling via `ActionChains` doesn't work for grid.

So, to get all images you should write custom logic that focuses grid, scrolls via keyboard events and then checks if grid y is changed (it is the only element that indicates that position of pointer was changed)

1. Click on `.uitk-tab.active` last element focuses grid.
2. Grid itself is first element by locator `[role=tabpanel] .uitk-layout-grid`
3. You call `getBoundingClientRect()` to get it's y and fire keyboard down until it wouldn't stop change
4. You wait for images amount are stop changing (rendered)
5. And then you get their src.

Be aware, that this code would work only for similar rendering model.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains, Keys

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(value_func, timeout=10, interval=2):
    start_time = time.time()
    value = None
    while value_func() != value:
        value = value_func()
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not stop changing within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)
    return value

def get_images():
    return driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[src*=https]')

def continuous_scroll():
    def get_grid_y():
        grid = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=tabpanel] .uitk-layout-grid')
        return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().y', grid)

    break_condition = False
    while not break_condition:
        grid_y = get_grid_y()
        for i in range (10):
            actionChains.send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if grid_y == get_grid_y():
            break_condition = True

driver.get("https://www.hoteles.com/en/ho572087/bahia-calma-beach-pajara-spain/?chkin=2023-09-15&chkout=2023-09-19&destType=MARKET&destination=Pajara%2C%20Canary%20Islands%2C%20Spain&expediaPropertyId=13461879&latLong=28.350619%2C-14.108076&neighborhoodId=6049907&pwaThumbnailDialog=thumbnail-gallery&pwa_ts=1694779934296&referrerUrl=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaG90ZWxlcy5jb20vSG90ZWwtU2VhcmNo&regionId=182358&rfrr=HSR&rm1=a2&searchId=ea11e221-09ee-419a-ac65-9331937627c8&selected=1157224&selectedRatePlan=286251325&selectedRoomType=219960804&sort=RECOMMENDED&top_cur=USD&top_dp=105&useRewards=false&userIntent=&x_pwa=1")
locator = 'img[src*=https]'
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(get_images)
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.uitk-tab.active')[-1].click()
continuous_scroll()
images = wait_for_value_to_stop_changing(get_images)
for img in images:
    data = img.get_attribute('src')
    print(data)
print(len(images))
```

Comment: It still doesn't get all photos, but get much more than before. Thanks

Comment: @keyboardNoob try to play with waits. Increase interval, etc. For sure issue is rendering time

Comment: even if I increase to 60 seconds it returns the same amount of photos. So I don't know

Comment: How many images should be from that link? What images aren't got?

Comment: it should get all images from gallery. In this case about 60 photos

Comment: @keyboardNoob see **UPD** section explanation and third code snippet. At least it gives you direction (and solves case with current page)